# Exporting 13 m records, 5 cols from Oracle to Teradata?

Tags: oracle, teradata

What's the most straightforward way to do this? Some googling turns up a bunch of quite old forum posts about ora2td, but I can't actually find the software itself. This makes me believe it may not be around/supported anymore. It's 13M records with 5 columns...is it realistic to just do a csv export/import? Is there a better way?

Comment: TPT using an ODBC connection to Teradata

Comment: Could you bulk export from Oracle to a named pipe that redirects into a TPT Load operator? Otherwise, @dnoeth has a solid, simpler suggestion. :)

Comment: flat file of such small volume should not be a problem. CSV to BTEQ.